# Pusher file script, next typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, pusher

I'm trying to import a script made in javascript,I'm working with typescript on nextjs React.
But I have this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1sL6.png)
Could I do something from my script?

I had more error, but were about how I imported the srcipt: now I import putting on next.conifg.js:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6aCs.png)

and import on the component:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Uki.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Now I try to import the script with next line:
const PusherPushNotifications = await import('@pusher/push-notifications-web');
But I have this error:
Error: Cannot start SDK, service worker missing: No file found at /service-worker.js